# Recurring calendar control - Jquery

Tags: jquery, outlook

I am looking for a jquery control to imitate the behavior of outlook's recurring scheduling. I've been looking for for the last few days but have come up with any real result. All the controls I find are calendar controls. Non of them implements the recurrence features.

Sample of Outlook's recurring screen:

[image]
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably have to build a form from scratch. It doesn't look like too formidable of a task.

Answer (score 0):

How about this jQuery plugin https://github.com/collective/jquery.recurrenceinput.js ?